# Can you use variables to reference table columns in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object

Let's say I've got a table that I'm trying to convert. Its got column names Item1, Item2... Item25. I don't have control over the column names, I'm converting from this into a better structure.

Because there's a pattern to the naming convention, I can create the column names on the fly. The problem is that when I try to use my variable as an object key, it gets passed through as a literal instead of the contents of the variable.

For instance, this works:

```
if !order.item1.empty?
  OrderItem.create(
  :item => order.item1,
  :quantity => order.qty1,
  :price => order.price1
)
```

But rather than make 25 variations of that by hand, I'd like to do something like

```
i = 1
while i < 25
    item_ref = "item" + i.to_s
    if !order.item_ref.empty?
    OrderItem.create(
        :item => order.item_ref,
        etc...)
    i += 1
    end
end
```

But of course this doesn't work. Rails tries to look up order.item_ref instead of order.item1, which doesn't exist.

I've hit this issue a couple of times on various projects, any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order.send item_ref`; Also, use `25.times do |i|` (starts at 0) or `(1..25).each do |i|` rather than your own loop.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. And thanks for the tip about better loop habits!

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't encourage you to use this kind of design but.. anyway.. you can do what you're trying using the `send()` method. As in `order.send("item + i.to_s")`...

Answer (score 0):

try this
it works in my case

```
i = 1
while i < 25
  item_ref = "item" + i.to_s
  unless order[item_ref].empty?
    OrderItem.create :item => order.item_ref,:blah blah ...
    i += 1
 end
end
```