# How to get a attribute from an instance of an ActiveRecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using the following to try to return a value from my database.

```
rate = @table_selection.constantize.where(age: quote_profile.age, risk_profile =>  true)
```

I am using variables to look up the value age is one and the risk_profile is a variable that contains a string representing the column name of "standard_rate" stored as a decimal.  I am trying to lookup the value.  Age is unique in the database.

However instead of the value I am getting this returned:

```
'Rate::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe357c7a528'
```

which is what I am asking for with the 'where'.

How can I get the actual value from the column I am referencing in the where clause?  I need this because I want to use the rate as an input to a create action...

schema table:

```
create_table "ten_year_term_rates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "age"
    t.decimal  "standard_rate"
    t.decimal  "premium_rate"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
end
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what is returned

Comment: sorry it was there but in a < > tag so not visible.

Comment: Don't use the code snippet feature for ruby. Its just for HTML/JS/CSS examples that are runnable in the browser. Code should be indented by four spaces, you can do that by selecting the lines and pressing ctrl + k (cmd + k) or pressing the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As '#pluck' doesn't work for you, try to use method `#map`. It will give return array of values that you can use later on.

```
rate = @table_selection.constantize.where(age: quote_profile.age, risk_profile =>  true).map { |record| record.send risk_profile }
```

Comment: thank you but this returns: [["age", 18], ["standard_rate", "t"]]  but the value of standard_rate for age 18 is not "t" in the database is 20.0

Comment: Perhaps its the way I am creating the quote:    @quote = Quote.new(rate: rate)?

Comment: I've just created `Rate` model with all the above fields. And run the query, the return value was `[0.20]`. Could you provide table schema for rates table, please?

Comment: here is the table:    create_table "ten_year_term_rates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "age"
    t.decimal  "standard_rate"
    t.decimal  "premium_rate"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
  end

Comment: added the table in the post bc formating issues here

Comment: Ok, try `pluck('ten_year_term_rates.stable_rate')`

Comment: Oh, wait. I know why the code doesn't work. Your `where` clause is incorrect. You try to filter `ten_year_term_rates` by `risk_profile: true`, but the table doesn't have that column

Comment: the risk_profile is a variable containing the column name "standard_rate" I have researched that is the way to get a variable named column into the where clause risk_profile => true  But you may be right and there is something I am not doing correctly here

Comment: @simplytrue I've updated the answer. Try that one, please

Comment: thank you again for helping - however as I stated I am using a variable to identify the column so I cannot use the column name as it is dynamically generated.

Comment: @simplytrue oh, ok. I've updated answer one more time

Comment: The nature of the dynamic column name makes it impossible to use the actual column name in the database query it has to be a variable - so map will not work because it includes and actual column name.

Comment: @simplytrue I've changed answer to use map with `#send`. Should work with dynamic column now

Answer (score 0):

```
rate = @table_selection.constantize.where("age = ? OR risk_profile = ?", quote_profile.age, true)
```

Comment: use `OR` or `AND`  operator according to your requirement.

Comment: This returns the same: TenYearTermRate::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fe35c455578  which is an ActiveRelation instance

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but had to do it without the where clause.  Here is the code:

```
 rate_record = @table_selection.constantize.find_by(age: quote_profile.age)
```

The find_by statement gets the number (data) I am looking for then I call

```
 rate = rate_record.send(risk_profile)
```

which is a way to call a method when using a variable.  I got the idea from this answer on here:  [Can you use variables to reference table columns in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658196/can-you-use-variables-to-reference-table-columns-in-rails)

Not sure why find_by works and where does not if anyone has a better solution that can be done in one line I am all for it...